# Navigation Menu onClick/hover

Tags: jquery, css, sass

I have a navigation menu with 8 links, 3 of which have sub menus. When I hover over the links, the color changes from gray to gold. When I hover over links with sub menus it displays the sub menu.

I created an onClick event via jQuery for the links with sub menus so that when it's clicked it will display the sub menu and leave it on the screen and change the link color to gold (the hover color).

However, once you click on one of the links with the sub menus the hover color change no longer works on the other links with sub menus but it does still work for the normal links.

```
home rules bonusrolls attendance reserves addons gallery info
```

Of the above, bonusrolls, attendance and addons have submenus.

So for example, starts off everything is working fine. Click on bonusrolls, it shows its sub menu and changes bonusrolls to gold permanently. Now whenever I hover over attendance or addons it stays gray, but I hover over home, rules, reserves, gallery or info and it hovers to gold.

```
#nav_whatever = sub menus
#whatever_menu = link
```

**jQuery**

```
$("a#bonusrolls_menu").click(function () {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#nav_bonusrolls').css('display', 'block');
  $('#nav_attendance').css('display', 'none');
  $('#nav_addons').css('display', 'none');
  $("a#bonusrolls_menu").css('color','#e97e1b');
  $("a#attendance_menu").css('color','#CCC');
  $("a#addons_menu").css('color','#CCC');
});
```

**CSS (SCSS)**

```
#main_nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    word-spacing: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
    width: 100%;

    li {
        float: left;
        padding: 0 0 0 15px;

        &.nav_dropdown:hover {
            #nav_bonusrolls, #nav_attendance, #nav_addons {
                display: inline;
            }
        }

        ul {
            &#nav_bonusrolls, &#nav_attendance, &#nav_addons {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 10px 0 0 0;
                font-size: .7em;
                word-spacing: 1px;

                li {
                    margin-left: 10px;
                    display: inline;
                }
            }

            &#nav_bonusrolls {
                margin: 0 0 0 -18px;
            }

            &#nav_attendance {
                margin: 0 0 0 -125px;
            }

            &#nav_addons {
                margin: 0 0 0 -333px;
            }
        }
    }

    a:link, a:visited, a:active {
        color: #CCC;
    }

    a:hover {
        color: #e97e1b;
    }
}
```

Edit:
http://oi39.tinypic.com/30sjz14.jpg

That's an image of what I'm talking about. This shows where I've clicked bonusrolls and it's highlighted and showed the menu but you can see I'm hovering over addons and it's not changing colors. Or rather you can't see my mouse (derp) but I'm hovering over addons in this image. lol

**Fiddle**
Fullscreen
http://jsfiddle.net/SLNuJ/1/embedded/result/
With Code
http://jsfiddle.net/SLNuJ/1

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which will attract more people to answer your question. In its current form, it's very difficult to experience your problem first hand.

Comment: I've fixed your problem and provided the working code. Hopefully, I'll get a vote up and accept :). This problem was indeed tricky.

Comment: Your fix worked for me. Thank you! I voted and accepted as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding the `color: #CCC` to the elements inline as part of the click handler. Since these are inlined, they override anything specified in the CSS files. Since you are changing color on hovering through the CSS files, they are not showing up.

I have fixed the problem in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SLNuJ/2/

The only change is to your JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a#bonusrolls_menu").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#nav_bonusrolls').css('display', 'block');
        $('#nav_attendance').css('display', 'none');
        $('#nav_addons').css('display', 'none');
        $("a#bonusrolls_menu").css('color', '#e97e1b');
        $("a#attendance_menu").css('color', '');
        $("a#addons_menu").css('color', '');
    });

    $("a#attendance_menu").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#nav_attendance').css('display', 'block');
        $('#nav_bonusrolls').css('display', 'none');
        $('#nav_addons').css('display', 'none');
        $("a#attendance_menu").css('color', '#e97e1b');
        $("a#bonusrolls_menu").css('color', '');
        $("a#addons_menu").css('color', '');
    });

    $("a#addons_menu").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#nav_addons').css('display', 'block');
        $('#nav_bonusrolls').css('display', 'none');
        $('#nav_attendance').css('display', 'none');
        $("a#addons_menu").css('color', '#e97e1b');
        $("a#bonusrolls_menu").css('color', '');
        $("a#attendance_menu").css('color', '');
    });
});
```

In place of setting the color to be `#CCC`, just remove the color from the element's inline style.

P.S.: Use the "Tidy Up" button provided by JSFiddle. It really makes your code look good.